# Can AssemblyName.Version throw an error?

Tags: c#, exception, version, .net-assembly

I want to know if `AssemblyName.Version` could ever encounter an **error**, for example when trying to retrieve it from the manifest file.

can I **manually modify** the assembly version somewhere outside the VS (e.g. a text editor) for a file and put in an **invalid version format** so that when trying to retrieve and compare it with another version I would get an exception of some sort.

if such an edit is possible, would this `AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName("path")` succeed?

Comment: it'd probably take less time to test your theory than post a question about it

Comment: The assembly version is embedded into the assembly at compile time - it's not read from a file. So no, you can't break it like that.

Comment: @Jonesey I tried testing it :) . I couldn't figure a way of hacking the version.

Comment: @Matthew Watson, thanks! that answers my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MajorVersion`, `MinorVersion`, `BuildNumber` and `RevisionNumber` are stored in the assembly with 2 bytes each. Someone determined could change these values, but there is no possible 'invalid' value, because each 2 byte value is interpreted as an unsigned integer between in the range 0 to `UInt16.MaxValue - 1`

As such, altering these values in the (unsigned) assembly would simply change the apparent version of the assembly.

The property `AssemblyName.Version` simply returns the value of the field populated when the assembly is loaded, and can not throw an exception.

That's not to say you couldn't corrupt your assembly in other ways...